# Housekeeping of the .task index in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Some time ago I stumbled on the `.task` index in ElasticSearch. It looks like ElasticSearch creates an entry in this index for every bulk insert or bulk delete.

Thus, I wondered, if I have to do some housekeeping for cleaning up the index. Currently, my index consists of ~70.000 entries, increasing. I tried to implement a cron job deleting all completed tasks via a bulk delete.

However,

1. ElasticSearch is telling me that accessing the index might be forbidden in future major releases:
   `this request accesses system indices: [.tasks], but in a future major version, direct access to system indices will be prevented by default`
2. ElasticSearch is preventing me from deleting the tasks by telling me, my user is mssing the required grants:
   `org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSecurityException: action [indices:data/write/delete/byquery] is unauthorized for user [user] with roles [superuser] on restricted indices [.tasks], this action is granted by the index privileges [delete,write,all]`

So I wonder, do I have to do any housekeeping for this index? Or is there another more elegant way to prevent the Elastic from keeping all that task information (for example a configuration I am missing)?

Answer (score 1):

The `.task` index only contains a historical data reference. As per [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex-task-api)

> If the request contains wait_for_completion=false, Elasticsearch performs some preflight checks, launches the request, and returns a task you can use to cancel or get the status of the task. Elasticsearch creates a record of this task as a document at _tasks/<task_id>.

By default, it grows forever until you take action on it. You can safely delete this index at scheduled times (it will be recreated automatically - unless you have [disabled auto-creation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-creation)) with the root elastic user or another user with sufficient, or put an [ILM](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/set-up-lifecycle-policy.html) on it.

Typically it is not recommended to operate on the . system indices directly perhaps this is still a valid case with tasks.

There is zero guarantee that this won't change in future releases. Most likely the housekeeping will be made part of the product at some point. But I imagine it's not high on their priority list